# Looking for movie title about a city under a kitchen sink

Tags: story-identification

All I know is 2 kids find Aditya under their sink and the little boy goes there.. Please help if you can.

Answer (score 2):

The Secret Kingdom:http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0144596/.

> Three kids discover a tiny kingdom beneath their kitchen sink and are
>   drawn inside, becoming involved with the miniature world's civil war.

movies.tvguide.com: http://movies.tvguide.com/the-secret-kingdom/133963

> THE SECRET KINGDOM is a strange, off-kilter children's feature that
>   dwindles into a state of ennui. New Orleans teen Mark (Billy O') is
>   followed home one day by a mysterious old lightning-rod salesman
>   (Gueyden T. Verret). His sister Callie (Tricia Dickson) is minding
>   their little brother Zak (Andrew Ducote) during their parents'
>   absence. Zak's toy walkie-talkie picks up a distress-call originating
>   from beneath their home's kitchen sink. There sits a tiny, thriving
>   city, surrounded by other tiny lands and bodies of water. Zak shows
>   Mark the marvel, and the older boy is suddenly teleported into the
>   place--called Relkin--by technician Chartwell (Gerald S. O'Laughli...

---

**Probably Not The Answer**

*The Indian in the Cupboard*